# How to execute Microsoft Teams app again when the app was removed from App Studio

Tags: visual-studio-code, microsoft-teams

I have tried different samples apps and I am getting the same error. If I create a new team app it works fine but if I remove the app from AppStudio or teams, then I cannot install/execute the app again.

I am using visual studio code with a simple Teams Tab Application code.
This is the error in teams (web with Chrome or Edge)

> "App not found, Please verify the app and it's access permissions".

This is the main log error:

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'customBots' of undefined
        at Function.t.getAppAnalyticsData (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.1-app.min-46191d5.js:1:3875125)
        at e.getAppInformationForTelemetry (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/lazy-ng1-mod-extensibility-dialogs.min-4642d77.js:1:202134)
        at e.logViewAppActionForTelemetry (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/lazy-ng1-mod-extensibility-dialogs.min-4642d77.js:1:200224)
        at https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/lazy-ng1-mod-lpc-services.min-72bf322.js:1:134587 undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you are using Teams Toolkit? If so, when you create the app in Visual Studio/ Visual Studio Code it is ALSO creating an app in App Studio in your personal account behind the scenes. If you choose to DELETE that app in App Studio, then Teams Toolkit has nothing behind the scenes to hook in to to redeploy. I think (can't check right now) that the app source code will have a manifest file somewhere - you can add this manually back to App Studio using the "import" function.

Comment: Hi jonathan, I agree with Hilton solution, could you please try as suggested above and if it works for you please upvote the answer.